# Conflict in toString default and Overriden toString

Tags: java

If I override with the real implementation of toString it gives different result compared with default toString implementation.Please help me to understand why different results come.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return getClass().getName()+"@"+Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

**Output for Above:**

```
leo.test.Teste@addbf1
```

**Output for Default:**

```
leo.test.Teste@19821f
```

**Whole Code :**

```
public class Teste 
{
    public  static void main(String args[])
    {
        Teste t = new Teste();
        System.out.println(t);      
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName()+"@"+Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the specific question here?

Comment: Question is - Why does this happen?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience updated.

Comment: By adding a method toString you have changed the class and therefore the native hashCode that is returned.  If you override hashCode to return a semantic hash then this will not change.

Comment: How did you call the default toString() method? Did you actually call both toString() calls on the same Object?

Comment: I tried by commenting the toString implementaion too.

Comment: even more - default `hashCode()` function is returning something like memory offset, so every time you run this code - you will get different values

Comment: @msangel you _may_ get different values, but I've tried running something multiple times, and creating `new` objects that I thought would change the address, but it got the same hash code.  This kind of behavior **may** fool someone into thinking the default hashCode is supposed to be a consistent value.  But you're right that it can't be counted on.  And I'm sure it depends on the implementation.

Comment: I don't see, in your code, where you are calling and printing the super implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem is the default implementation of `hashCode()`, it [may be based on the adress of the object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29). So, if you test two times (one with the overrided method, one without), you can have different results.

If you try it like that:

```
public class TestToString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestToString tts = new TestToString ();
        System.out.println(tts);
        System.out.println(tts.superToString());
    }

    public String superToString()
    {
        return super.toString ();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName()+"@"+Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
}
```

you will have the same result for the two methods:

```
com.test.TestToString@8dc8569
com.test.TestToString@8dc8569
```